# implications of sharing in-memory sqlite with multiple process

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, python-multiprocessing

Initially I have created an sqlite database('temp.db') and shared its connection to multiple process. I started to get lots of database locked error.
I needed database for temporary storage only. The only operation performed are INSERT and SELECT on a single TABLE also no COMMIT is done on the database.

To overcome above lock issue I have created an in-memory(':memory:') sqlite database and shared its connection to multiple process. I have not run into any database lock error until now.

In both the cases I have not used any locking mechanisms. Using in first case might have resolved the issue, but dont want to increase execution time.

Is locking needed in second case? What could be other pitfalls to care for? Its impact on long running application?

Comment: How are you sharing it?

Comment: passing as argument to multiprocessing.Process( target=func, args=(db,))

Comment: And what is `db`? (Sqlite supports sharing the same in-memory database between different connections in the same process, but not between different processes, so I strongly suspect whatever you're doing is not working the way you think)

Comment: Ubuntu20.04 LTS. Here, db = sqlite.connect(':memory:', check_same_thread=False).

Comment: Yeah... that's not how it works. If you're trying to open a database in another process using the stringified db, you probably have files likes `<sqlite3.Connection object at 0xXXXXXXX>` littering your drive.